# AuthenticationError sending a notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a request with PostMan to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
with this body

```
{
"data": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "notification.newcomment.title",
        "body": "notification.newcomment.body",
        "click_action": "/video/a2df5da5-a0d8-4a27-1588-08d64fb9bf88",
        "icon": "null"
    }
},
"to": "xxxxx"
}
```

I receive from Firebase this response:

```
{
"multicast_id": 6589525169180682671,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "error": "AuthenticationError"
    }
]}
```

I don't understand what is the problem of the AuthenticationError.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to resolve AuthenticationError and send the firebase notification.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all the relevant code you're using to send the message.  You're probably doing something wrong there.

Comment: I'm using Postman to send the request

Answer (score 1):

Now it works.
I think it was a Firebase problem because I haven't changed anything in the request.